# Using stripslashes on a database row php

Tags: php, stripslashes

```
{$row['info']}
```

How do I use stripslashes() php function on this?

I've tried :
`stripslashes({$row['info']})`, doesnt work and this: `{stripslashes($row['info'])}`

Neither work.

Do I have to use a $var first??

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? That isn't what `stripslashes` is for.

Comment: @meagar: If his `$row['info'] = "This is the foo\'s place!";` then `echo stripslashes($row['info']);` is exactly the thing he should be doing.

Comment: @Kalle That's true, but irrelevant. My point is, his data should never be in that state. There is no way he should ever wind up using stripslashes while *echoing* something. He's not managing his data correctly if he has to unescape things before displaying them; they should be automatically escaped/unescaped as they go into/out of the database.

Comment: @Meagar: Its actually very relevant as that's what he is asking. Yes of course I agree with you, that he should avoid these types of situations. However that's a side-note for the straightforward question he asked.

Comment: @Kalle "How do I do this completely unnecessary and wrong thing" is not a straightforward question unless you're content to allow such ignorance and bad practices to continue. I'm actually concerned with helping the OP *learn* something.

Comment: @Meagar: You see the mysql result part. I see that somebody is trying to use stripslashes inside heredoc syntax. So, yeah, teaching the OP is a good thin, but that should be in aditional to the question he is asking. If everybody starts thinking outside the box and ignore the actual question.. Then the hole community will top giving direct answers and start theorizing about good practice and "how it should be done".

Comment: @Kalle How am I ignoring his actual question? You'll notice that I answered his question, exactly as he asked it. Then, in the *comments*, which are specifically for commentary, I'm asking for more details and trying to explain why the premis of his question is wrong. I'm completely in the right here, while your example remains contrived and irrelevant. If you're using stripslashes inside heredoc syntax, you're *also* doing it wrong and you don't know any better than the OP. That *is not what stripslashes is for*.

Comment: I know you did everything right. -- You firstly said that stripslashes aren't made for this - incorrect. Then you said, that his questions point is irrelevant - ?!?!. And then you made a personal opinion on what is being asked. This questions format is very straight forward, hes method on inserting the entries to db is most likely wrong, agreed. But the question definitely isn't "How do I do this...unnecessary and wrong thing". I made my points clear, so that's that. For the record, your answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

[`stripslashes`](http://ca.php.net/stripslashes) returns the modified string, leaving its argument unchanged. You have to assign the result to a variable:

```
$var = stripslashes($row['info']);
```

That said, why are you doing this? You almost certainly shouldn't be. There is no reason to strip slashes on data coming from the database, unless you've double-escaped the slashes when the data was inserted.

Comment: hehe, you answered while I typed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat confusing.

`stripslashes()` takes parameter and converts backslashed symbols to normal ones. more over, it does not affect the parameter. it returns stripped version.

so `$result = stripslashes($source)` or `$row["info"]` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = stripslashes($row['info']);
```

is more correct. Or in string, use it like this

```
echo "something".stripslashes($row['info'])." some more thingy";
```

Answer (score 0):

It almost seems, that you are using [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) because of your {}. Question, is why? Are you seriously displaying your results like this?:

```
echo <<<my_results
Info: {$row['info']}
my_results;
```

Well, since that is cool way to do so then here is your fix:

```
$row_info = stripslashes($row['info']);
echo <<<my_results
Info: {$row_info}
my_results;
```

However, I do not recommend that approach. Rather do it like this:

```
echo 'Info:' . stripslashes($row['info']);
```

Because `{stripslashes($row['info'])}` doesn't work indeed and `stripslashes({$row['info']})` is an anecdote!